# Bornology with closed basis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a regular convex bornological space. I want to show that $\mathcal{B}$ has a basis consisting of $\mathcal{O}$-closed sets, where $\mathcal{O}$ is a locally convex vector topology on $X$ with a zero neighbourhood basis consisting of absolutely convex $\mathcal{B}$-Bornivores (subsets of $X$ that absorb all Elements of $\mathcal{B}$). Let $A \in \mathcal{B}$ then since $\mathcal{B}$ is a convex vector bornology we have that the disked hull $B := \mbox{disk}(A)$ is $\mathcal{B}$ bounded. Now I want to show that $\overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}}$ is also $\mathcal{B}$-bounded. Since $X \setminus \overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}} \in \mathcal{O}$ for $x \in X \setminus \overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}}$ there exists a absolutely convex $\mathcal{B}$-Bornivore $D$ such that $D \subseteq X \setminus \overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}} - x$. $D$ is a $\mathcal{B}$-Bornivore meaning it absorbs $B$ hence there exists $\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $t B \subseteq D \subseteq X \setminus \overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}} - x$ for all $|t| \leq \epsilon$. From this I conclude $x + \epsilon B \subseteq X \setminus \overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}}$. Now $(X,\mathcal{B})$  being regular implies that $\mathcal{O}$ is a Hausdorff topology. Now I want to assume by contraposition $\overline{B}^{\mathcal{O}} \not\in \mathcal{B}$ and derive a contradiction using the Hausdorff property of $\mathcal{O}$. At this point I can't seem to find any argument.

Comment: I do not think that this is true. There are bornologies such that the corresponding locally convex topology is trivial, see, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221476/do-hausdorff-locally-convex-inductive-limits-always-exist/221478#221478